# Why is the field of view of my lens narrower than my calculations show it should be?

Tags: field-of-view, calculations, aerial-photography

The field of view of the Panasonic GH4 Micro Four Thirds camera with a 12mm lens is 84°.

At a height of 120m, pointing straight down, I should be able to see 216m<sup>1</sup> of ground across the diagonal of the frame. In reality I'm seeing 180m.

Either my maths/understanding of fov is wrong, or I'm not at 120m, I'm trying to ascertain which is the case.

1. 2 * tan((84°/2)) * 120m = 216m

Comment: To save everyone else wondering where 216m comes from, I've put in the obvious bit of maths. If you're doing something else, please change things appropriately.

Comment: The focal-length varies with focus and is usually quoted with focus at infinity. Try changing focus. Also, are you measuring the height from the sensor-plane?

Comment: @Itai in 120m, I doubt the difference between the sensor plane and the end of the lens or wherever else is going to make much difference!

Comment: Is this a 12mm prime lens? Or a zoom lens that includes 12mm it its range of focal lengths?

Comment: The math is actually much simpler. The expected diagonal field of view with a sensor diagonal of 'd', a focal length of 'f' at a distance of 'D' is simply (d/f)*D or in this case (21,6mm/12mm)*120m = 216m.

Comment: @jarnbjo: Both formulas are useful. They differ based on whether you take the sensor size or the lens' specified AoV as your given value.

Comment: @WarrenYoung Not really, since the lens' angle of view depends on the sensor size. Starting with the sensor size and focal length to get the lens' angle of view to calculate the field of view based on tha aov is just an unnecessary step.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some possible sources of error:

1. Manufacturer stated focal lengths are often rounded favorably or sometimes plain exaggerated (e.g. a 200mm might well be only 190mm).
2. Focal lengths are also stated at infinity focus, lenses change focal length when focusing (though it is more common for a lens to get wider as you focus closer not narrower).
3. Sensor sizes are not always specified accurately (if this is how the AOV was calculated), even within the same format from the same manufacturer there will be variations of around 0.1mm that effect your angle of view.
4. RAW editors crop your images, as most demosaicing algorithms use neighbourhood operations (where the value of a pixel depends on surrounding pixels) in the edges of the image there are no neighbouring pixels so these areas are cropped out of the final image. Usually the amount lost is only around 4 pixels from each edge.
5. Lens distortion corrections applied by the camera JPEG engine or during RAW conversion change the effective focal length and/or result in the image needing to be cropped.
6. Measurement errors in your 120m or 216m figures.

Some or all of these adding up are enough to explain the discrepancy. **If lens corrections are being applied that will be the biggest factor and could probably explain the result on it's own**. The next most likely/largest source of error will be in the 12mm focal length figure.

Here's a worked example. If the lens focal length is really 12.4mm and the sensor is 0.1mm smaller than spec then your diagonal angle of view will be 79.61°. If you're really at 117m and if lens corrections + demosaicing are causing you to lose 3% off each edge then you would expect to see 183m, which with less than 2% error could be measured as 180m.

Comment: Multiple factors stacking up make a lot of sense. I'm going to verify the 120m with a physical measurement (120m fishing line hung from the drone). Then at least I can rule that one out.

Comment: @BenJO I would try and rule out lens correction first as it's the most likely cause. Are you shooting RAW or JPEG?